# JavaScript Module Pattern: user implementable function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, iife

So I'm using the Module pattern to create my own 'API' with private and public methods and properties. So far so good.

However: I want to add a public function/hook that can be changed/implemented by the user.

The problem however is that when the function is called from within the module it still knows the previous definition. How can I make sure to use the overridden definition without having to use the variable name within the module?

```
var test = (function(){
    'use strict';
    var version = "1.7.0";

    var a = function(){
        console && console.log("Test");
        defineC();
        c();
    };

    var _b = function(){
        a();
    };

    var c = function(){
        //User implementable
    };

    return {
        version: version,
        a: a,
        c: c
    };
})();

function defineC(){
    test.c = function(){
        console && console.log("My own function");
    };
}

test.a();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*without having to use the variable name*"? You can do `test.c()`, `this.c()`, `local_test_alias.c()` or anything else

Comment: Should `defineC` be part of your module or should the user just be able to assign to `test.c`?

Comment: Now the only way to keep use the correct implementation of c in a is by calling test.c() and not by simply calling c()

defineC shouldn't be part of the module. User should just be able to assign his own function to c. And the methods inside the closure should use the updated c implementation.

Comment: If you want to call `c()` as a local variable and you don't want to expose `defineC(userFn) { c = userFn; }` from the module, there's no way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your overriding function as an argument for your IIFE

Like so

```
var test = (function(userFunction){
   'use strict';
   var version = "1.7.0";

   var a = function(){
        console.log("Test");
        c();
   };

   var _b = function(){
        a();
   };

   var c = userFunction;

   return {
        version: version,
        a: a,
        c: c
   };
})(defineC);

function defineC(){
   console.log("My own function");
}

test.a();
```

https://jsbin.com/vuwenesehu/edit?js,console

Comment: So in case of two functions:

var test = (function(a, b){...})(def1, def2);

When will everything launch then? Say that def1 and def2 (or defineC) are loaded from another JS file.

Comment: `const def1 = function () { console.log('def1'); }
const def2 = function () { console.log('def2'); }

const test = (function(def1, def2) {
 // here you use def1 and def2
 })(def1, def2)
`

Comment: IIFE will run as soon as you define it; Unless you use those given parameters, they wont run. This means, if you pass to your IIFE two functions, they won't run unless you execute them, ex: def1(); def2();

Comment: Okay, thanks!

But so there is no way with this pattern to provide user implementable hooks without them being predefined and passed when loading the module?

Comment: Furthermore: in defineC I still can't use version. I have to type test.version...

Comment: Mmm what are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe I don't get your point

Comment: What I am trying to do is let users implement some 'hooks' of their own.
And then the internal functions of the module should run those hooks instead of the empty ones provided by default.

However now I have to run the hooks as varname.hook() as otherwise it would still use the empty one from the module. And I prefer not to use the varname, just in case the varname is changed or copied to another one.